# solve sum of square roots using a single functiom using Newton's Method

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I have to estimate $n= \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$ using Newton's Method of approximation but I have to determine a **single function** which can be used to estimate $n$.

P.S: The function should not involve radical expressions (nth root of constants or variables)

So, I just **need to know what the single function** is. I can solve the rest myself
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Considering that radical roots appear in conjugate pairs, you could construction a rational function that has the root $n=\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3}$ as follows,

$$[x-(\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{3})][x-(\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{3})] = x^2 +4 -2\sqrt{7}x$$

$$ (x^2 +4 -2\sqrt{7}x)(x^2 +4 + 2\sqrt{7}x) = (x^2+4)^2-28x^2 $$

Thus, the function

$$f(x)=(x^2+4)^2-28x^2$$ contains the roots $n=\sqrt{7}\pm \sqrt{3}$, as well as another pair.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**  Newton's method is a *root finder*, meaning given a function $f(x)$ it computes the root of $f(x)$, i.e. the special argument $\bar{x}$ such that $f(\bar{x}) = 0$.

You need for Newton's Method to find $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7}$. Can you find a function $f(x)$, which will have a root at this magic place?

Comment: Is it x^2 - n^2? where n = sqrt 3 + sqrt 7

Comment: @player_pi that won't work --$n^2 = 10+2\sqrt{21}$ which still has a radical. But a quartic polynomial will do just fine

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Say $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}$. Then $x^2=10+2\sqrt{21}$. There is still a radical left. You need to remove it to get to the function $f(x)$.

Comment: That's the point. my function cannot have a radical

Comment: The remaining radical can be easily removed. You should try it.